# Where can i see what is the thermal dissipation of a 5630 or 1W power led?

Tags: led

I looked a lot of datasheet from different distributors but i can't fint any information about thermal output.
Datasheets: http://greyghost.mooo.com/usb3led/BL-LS5730A.PDF
http://www.yujiintl.com/files/high-cri-led-datasheets/BX5730L-YUJI.pdf

Comment: Assume all the electrical input power is wasted as heat and you will get close to the real calue with some margin. If you have 100 lm/W white light, you are at roughly 25 % efficiency.

Comment: So if its a 1w power led, 0.75 is wasted as heat and only 25% the real brightness?

Comment: Yes. Modern LEDs have an efficiency of up to 35%. However the exact values also correspond to the color of the light.

Comment: @Kober  When you state that you've looked at a lot of datasheets, please post links to a few datasheets that you've looked into.

Comment: Only for you: http://greyghost.mooo.com/usb3led/BL-LS5730A.PDF
http://www.yujiintl.com/files/high-cri-led-datasheets/BX5730L-YUJI.pdf
there are the first and second result
Tell me please where are the thermal informations?

Comment: That information is **crucial**, Kober. **edit** your question and add it!

Comment: Ok, i edited, but i still dont know where can i find to the value. What should i look for in the datasheets?

Comment: It is fairly expensive to measure optical power in an integrating sphere integrated over the radiated spectrum and is not as relevant as eye corrected luminant flux or luminous intensity and dominant wavelength or CIE correctly colour coordinates. It's about as useful as knowing energy of the photon travelling with 200 THz frequency.  So just assume all of power input is waste heat and this may compensate for oversight in thermal resistance.  Lumens/Watt is the reference spec normally used.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_efficacy#Examples_2  will tell you that an efficacy of 100 lumens per watt emitted from neutral White LEDs are only 15% luminously efficient meaning 85% of Pd is heat.  Tungsten bulbs are 2% efficient, meaning 98% heat. Cree has broken their record with devices over 300 lumens /watt.http://www.cree.com/News-and-Events/Cree-News/Press-Releases/2014/March/300LPW-LED-barrier  at 5150 K and 350 mA

Comment: @Kober Pretty much! That assumed about 100 lm/W. Lower luminous efficiency = more power wasted as heat.

Comment: Effectively raw LED efficiency = lm/W *15% so 70LPW is  only 10% efficient and 200 LPW is 20% efficient.  This is then reduced by Luminaire  efficiency and power supply efficiency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a good first approximation, you can assume that 100% of the energy flowing into an LED gets converted to heat. Modern LEDs do have some 10-30% efficiency, so in reality, it's but 90%-70%, but for thermal design, the *order of magnitude* is often important to make sure a thermal design is sound. You'd, in the situation that you seem to be in, never built something that only has 10% of thermal headroom – simply because you can't even control your ambient temperature to that degree.

---

---

---

If you want to think about it (it really doesn't pay, usually):

You can find out the actual efficiency by calculating the power that goes into the LED – simply forward voltage times current – and divide the energy of the emitted light by that.

In some cases, datasheets even tell you the luminous efficiency. But that's typically the case for the more reputable manufacturers (OSRAM, Cree and so on). You picked two manufacturers that I don't know. I presume they make cheap LEDs.

What's the energy of the emitted light? For monochromatic LEDs, that's pretty simple: it's the amount of energy per photon, times the amount of photons emitted per second.

Energy per photon is very simple; from physics 101 we know

$$ E = \frac{hc}\lambda $$

with \$c=3\cdot 10^8 \frac{\text m}{\text s}\$ the speed of light, \$\lambda\$ the wavelength and \$h\$ Planck's constant, \$6.626 \cdot 10^{-34} \,\text{Js}\$.

However, in practical LEDs, the number of photons is seldom given – you just get "Luminous Flux" in Lumen (lm) instead – and that has a direct conversion to power, however only for specific wavelengths.

So, any **reasonably reputable** manufacturer will give you Lumen/Watt, *luminous efficacy*. If you take that, and compare it to the theoretic *ideal* efficacy for a 555nm source, namely 683 lm/W, you get your overall efficiency.

Let's do this for the BL-LS5730A1S1UWC-0.5W:

It has a "typical" output of 55 lm (I believe exactly nothing from this datasheet, but let's use that number) over an angle of (**what?** that is not even specified?!) let's say half a sphere, so let's double that. That gives you an estimated efficency of about \$\frac16\$; that means that 83% of your power is converted to heat.

These datasheets are really good for nothing. At least two of the values *opening angle* (sr, °), *luminous flux*(lm) and *luminous intensity* (cd) should be given. I'd encourage you to buy from someone who gives you a complete datasheet, so that you're not surprised later on.

Comment: +1 I think the full answer is given in your first paragraph. The rest can be safely deleted, to avoid massive confusion with details. Calculations of energy emitted through the light should be a different topic.

Comment: @AliChen hm, kinda like the second part :) I'll try to find a compromise

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm a little bit confused, I thought that the efficency will be about at least 50% or better. 10-15% not a good result. So there is more to develop. I will buy leds from ebay, i hope not suprised later on. Thanks the help.

Comment: @Kober really, don't buy LEDs on ebay. *sigh*. Ok, imagine you get a 10% effective LED for 20% less than you would have gotten them through a regular distributor. You get a bad datasheet from which you can only assume your LEDs belong to the worst brightness bins, no guarantees and especially certainly not the higher efficiency ones at all. Look around on http://mouser.com , http://newark.com , http://digikey.com and maybe even http://tme.eu (if you want the cheap stuff), but do yourself a favor and don't buy random stuff from ebay.